# 17.10 GUI problem when connectiong to Juniper/Pulse VPN

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openconnect

I am trying to connect to my job's Juniper VPN via openconnect. It works just fine on the *command line* I mean terminal :) I also installed the plugins and added it to NetworkManager GUI. When I want to connect, it gets the login form, which contains a domain selector drop-down. The problem is, I can not select what I want. The options are there, but when I click my selection, it gets reset (first option becomes selected again) and the focus jumps on the next control. I tried using the keyboard, tried filling out the rest of the form first, but to no avail. I also noticed that every time I pull down the list, a new icon appears on the launch bar. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded to use the GUI to connect to a Juniper VPN.
To do so, I have installed the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```

Then, when going to the VPN settings, in the Add VPN (+), there is a new entry "Cisco AnyConnect Compatible VPN (openconnect)" which allows to connect to a Juniper device.

Comment: The problem happens when you select Juniper/Pulse (not Cisco AnyConnect).

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the same question on openconnect mailing list, and they confirmed it. They know the cause and the solution, and said it will be corrected.